# DropDownList is not expanding inside a ScrollViewer

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

In my application i used a DropDownList inside a ScrollViewer. DropDownList is not expanding on clicking when it is inside the ScrollViewer. but it is expanding when the ScrollViewer is removed. What is the issue when it is not expanding inside the ScrollViewer. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem might be related to Height. You need to specify some appropriate Height to ScrollViewer in order to see expanded DropDownList.